# Using native SQL query without entity class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I need to create native SQL query with couple of unions and subqueries. It'll look approximately like this:

```
SELECT res.id, COUNT(*) as count_ids
FROM (
    SELECT a.id FROM ... a WHERE ... LIKE ('%:param%')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.id FROM ... b WHERE ... LIKE ('%:param%')
    UNION ALL
    ...
) res
GROUP BY res.id
ORDER BY count_ids asc
```

Result won't match any Entity I use in my application. Is it possible to create `ResultSetMapping` with "anonymous" object? Or is it, at least, possible to create an Entity that wouldn't create table next time I update schema, so I can map results to it?

Or is there any other Doctrine-friendly way to deal with such query? Making changes to database isn't possible though, as I'm dealing with legacy stuff that cannot be touched. I'd also strongly prefer if I did everything on database side, not involving much of PHP in it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Do you have a particular need to map results to a domain object? If not, you could use the DBAL to make a plain old query, which will return an array, as detailed in [the Symfony2 cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html) and [the Doctrine DBAL documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html):

```
$conn = $this->container->get('database_connection');
$sql = 'SELECT res.id, COUNT(*)...';
$rows = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: http://www.metod.si/get-doctrine2-dbal-connection-for-different-databases-in-symfony2/  => if you want to connect to more than 1 db

Answer (score 23):

Use **addScalarResult** method of **ResultSetMapping**

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

$rsm->addScalarResult('cnt', 'cnt');
$rsm->addScalarResult('id', 'id');

$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT count(*) AS  cnt, id_column as id FROM your_table group by id', $rsm);

$result = $query->getResult();

var_dump($result);
```

Result array:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'cnt' => int 1
      'id' => int 15
```

Comment: If you want fetch only `cnt` value you can change `getResult()` to `getSingleScalarResult()`. Your result will be `1`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it was a simple nonsense demo query, based on my real ones with similar grouping and returning of 2 columns