# Doctrine use count() in NativeQuery with ResultSetMapping

Tags: doctrine-orm, nativequery

i try to use NativeQuery of Doctrine. If i use my SQL ind Phpmyadmin i have the good result. If i use this, my var_dump return an empty array. I don't understand why.

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(id) as nb FROM app_facture f WHERE SUBSTR(f.datecreate_facture, 1, 4) = 2014 AND SUBSTR(f.numero_facture,1,1) != "E"';
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Acme\MyBundle\Entity\Facture', 'f');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'COUNT(id)', 'nb');

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery($sql,$rsm);

    $results = $query->getResult();

    var_dump($results);//return empty array
```

Thanks

Comment: Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860838/using-native-sql-query-without-entity-class/46743501#46743501

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'nb', 'id');
```

this worked for me.